# How do I use cross products to find the area of the quadrilateral in the $$-plane defined by $(0,0), (1,−1), (3,1)$ and $(2,8)$?

Tags: vectors, area, cross-product

How do I use cross products to find the area of the quadrilateral in the  $$-plane defined by  $(0,0),   (1,−1),   (3,1)$   and $(2,8)$?

So what I first do is find two vectors. Gonna use (0,0) as the starting point cause that's easier.

My two vectors:
$\left\langle 2,8,0\right\rangle$
and
$\left\langle 1,-1,0\right\rangle$

Now I calculate the cross product and get: $\left\langle 0,0,10\right\rangle$

Now I find the magnitude and get 10. Divide 10 by 2 and get 5 as my area. Now, that definitely makes no sense and it isn't the correct answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That formula is for the area of a *parallelogram*.

Your quadrilateral is not a parallelogram.

You could divide it into two triangles

and then find the area of each triangle by taking half of the magnitude of the cross-product

and then add the areas together.

Answer (score 3):

Take $\frac12$ of the cross product of the diagonal vectors $(3,1)$ and $(1,9)$.
$$\operatorname{Area}=\frac12 d_1 d_2 \sin (\widehat{d_1,d_2})$$

Comment: I will leave my answer, because I believe it is correct and it answered where OP's mistake was, but this approach is more elegant $(+1)$